# Loading a javascript file to webbrowser tool in windows phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am loading a url into webbrowser tool in windows phone. Now I want to invoke a javascript code which is not in the source code of url loaded. How can I do this? How can I load this javascript file intowebbrowser tool?

Comment: you could use InvokeScript method to load a javaScript file

Comment: Yes... actually where do I need to add the javascript code to existing webpage code? Can u suggest some samples?

Comment: When do you need to invoke the JS, after loading is completed or after certain thing happened in browser?

Comment: after loading is completed..